Read Custom Currency format of Excel file in Python without changes
I am reading an excel file which contains the following formats in the Price column for example.

£35.00
US$85.60
CAN$109.10

When I am reading the file using pd.read_excel, it changes the prices to digits like 35.00, 85.60 and 109.10. I am not doing any calculation with this column but I need to see different formats next to the Products itself.
I have tried using pd.read_excel(file_path, dtype = {'Price' : str} or even pd.read_excel(file_path, dtype = {'Price' : object}.
I have also tried changing the type of the column in dataframe as well but no use.
I am combining multiple files in a pandas dataframe with the same format so I don't need to change anything in this Price column. The files are in xls format.

Does this answer your question? pandas read excel as formatted

You should use pd.read_excel(file_path, dtype={"Price": object})


Could you please consider updating pandas and your backend engine (mine is openpyxl). pip install --upgrade pandas openpyxl. Maybe the issue is with your pandas library. 2) Also check that pandas is able to read the header properly. Maybe your dtype is not applied because of problem with reading the header. 3) try using different excel backend engines. pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx", engine = 'openpyxl')


I don't believe openpyxl supports the .xls file format.
